# Can not execute js.erb code rendered from an AJAX request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs, axios

I have a React app that sends POST requests to a Rails controller with the Axios library, that code looks like:

```
axios.post(update_url,{
    bunch_of_data: data
 }, {headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 }})
 .then(res => {
    const response_data = res.data;
    console.log(response_data);
});
```

The controller looks like:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :ensure_logged_in
  skip_before_action :authenticate_admin_user
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def update_feed
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render layout: false }
    end
  end
end
```

For AJAX requests from jQuery inside the Rails app, I don't have to usually do anything with the routes, but in this case, if I didn't have this default, I get the request as HTML:

```
post '/update_feed' => 'mycontroller#update_feed', as: :update_feed, defaults: { format: 'js' }
```

My Rails logs end up looking like:

```
Started POST "/update_feed" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-26 15:21:23 -0700
Processing by MyController#update_feed as JS
{"format"=>"js", "controller"=>"my_controller", "action"=>"update_feed"}
Rendering /update_feed.js.erb
Rendered /update_feed.js.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2433ms (Views: 9.0ms | ActiveRecord: 74.1ms)
```

It says it renders the js.erb file but nothing happens on the Rails side. However, I do see the `alert("!")` in my js.erb file printing from the response inside the React app (so I see `alert("!")` in my browser console). But why isn't it executing?

Comment: do u have udate_feed.js.erb file and what's it in?

Comment: I have an alert in there, but it only gets printed from the success block in my React app where a console.log lives.

Comment: I think..your code is clearly rendered as your console output. why do you think it doesn't working? check response by network tab  in your browser console.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen instead?

Comment: I was expecting an alert to pop up in my browser, from my js.erb file. No Javascript in that file is executing, but instead is printing the code from the file in my response to the axios success. Is it not possible to trigger a js.erb code execution from an axios ajax response?